# Swift - cycling through background images

Tags: image, animation, swift

I'm completely new to coding and I'm trying to learn Swift.  I'm trying to cycle through background images for an app.  The images I have are named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg.  When I try run the simulator, the "super.viewDidLoad()" line is highlighted green with the comment, "Thread 1, Breakpoint 3.1." Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var imageList = [UIImage]()

    for i in 1...4 {

        let imageName = "\(i).jpg"
        var image = UIImage(named:imageName)
        imageList.append(image)
    }

    self.myImageView.animationImages = imageList
    self.myImageView.animationDuration = 4.0
    self.myImageView.startAnimating()
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've set a breakpoint there. If there's a blue pointer to the left of the line, click it to disable it. Or, use the keyboard shortcut command-Y to disable all breakpoints.